# Python program running in memory

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a python program that loads a logistic regression model. I am trying to make a prediction with new incoming data every 5 seconds. The incoming data is passed into the code as a command line argument. The program runs ok but i dont want to keep loading the model every 5 seconds. Is there a way to have the model always loaded in memory?
My code is below

```
loaded_model = joblib.load(r'C:\LR_model.sav')
dataset = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
result = loaded_model.predict(dataset)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

memory is bound to the process, so once your process exits it's memory is freed. If you want keep your data loaded, you'll need to rewrite your program as a server process and setup some communication protocol for your client to ask for a new prediction (HTTP seems like a good fit here).